# How to set option value conditionally disabled when DB_values are greater than current time?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm able to fetch DB entries with their time, all the entries are getting into the select box properly entries which are having **time lesser** *than* **current time** are falling in ***if statement...***, as well as entries with **time greater** *than* **current time**, are falling in ***Else Sattement...***,

I want to show entries from both the **if-else** statement, but values falling in else statement should be disabled by nature, so that they won't get selected, here is my code please help

```js
<select name="gameSelect" v-model="fields.game_id" >
    <option v-for="gameinfo in gamesinfo" selected v-bind:key="gameinfo.id" v-bind:value="gameinfo.id">
        <div v-if="gameinfo.time < timestamp">
            {{ gameinfo.game_name }} / {{ gameinfo.time }}
        </div>
        <div v-else>
           Disabled {{ gameinfo.game_name }}  {{ gameinfo.time }}
        </div>
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:disabled` prop to add your date condition to disable option. In below example replace `YOUR CONDITION TO DISABLE` with date condition.

```
<select name="gameSelect" v-model="fields.game_id" >
    <option v-for="gameinfo in gamesinfo" selected :disabled="YOUR CONDITION TO DISABLE" v-bind:key="gameinfo.id" v-bind:value="gameinfo.id">
        <div v-if="gameinfo.time < timestamp">
        {{ gameinfo.game_name }} / {{ gameinfo.time }}
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            {{ gameinfo.game_name }}  {{ gameinfo.time }}
        </div>
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah code suggested by you is modified and now it's working how to show placeholder as select your option, it is missing now.